# Unity with google cardboard: Remove center divider with gear?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, stereo-3d, virtual-reality

I am a complete beginner with Unity and VR and I've downloaded a few demo scenes into Unity with Google Cardboard all set up.

These scenes work, however I have seen several VR applications where the stereo view (the 2 screens for the 2 different eyes) is NOT separated by Google's little divider with the gear icon at the bottom -

These applications look a lot cleaner and just have a split, stereo screen with no divider or anything. Here is a video of what I'm talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZC0ef604WU

There is no divider, just 2 stereo screens. I don't know what this is called.

I've downloaded some demos that have this but cannot figure out where/how they disabled Google's divider and moreover the black around the 2 screens.. How do you do this with Google cardboard's Main camera?

Please explain everything clearly as I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity select the "CardboardMain" gameobject. You will see a checkbox for Alignment Marker and Settings Button. Uncheck those and you should be set.